# Is there a way to run WSL AND a vm?

Tags: command-line, windows, hyper-v

I'm using WSL to run code on my windows machine and whilst it works, I'd really like to have a full ubuntu desktop environment so I can use command line tabs for example as well as unlocking all of the features the distro offers. Seeing as hyper-V is disabled, is there a way to get around this and run WSL *with* a VM?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can run WSL **and** a VM in VirtualBox, or VMWare or any other VM app that runs on Windows. What do you mean by "run WSL *with* WSL"? WSL is a sort of VM as it has its own kernel with some limitations. I think one can ["officially"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) run some kind of GUI in WSL in Windows 11.

Comment: Do you mean something like https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-desktop-windows-subsystem/?

Comment: Good question, I could never get VBox working once hyper-v was activated.